# Отправка закодированных данных по udp python

Tags: python, кодировка, udp, binary, hex

Мне нужно отправить строку данных по udp(пример: b’str’), но перед этой строкой нужно вставить один байт данных - двоичное число которое равняется номеру отправленной строки. Я знаю, что можно, что это можно сделать так: b’\x1’ + b’str’ - это первая отправленная строка. Однако этот первый байт будет в шестнадцатеричный системе счисления. Как тоже самое сделать в двоичной системе? Как проучить байтовую строку в двоичной системе?
И второй вопрос: как получать такую байтовую строку b’\x1’ в шестнадцатеричный системе и как такую строку получить из двоичной системе из числа типа int, к примеру из 1?

Comment: 1 байт — это 8 бит, каждый из которых может быть только 0 или 1. Никакой шестнадцатеричной системы в байтах не существует.

Comment: Если вы хотите просто записать в коде число в двоичном виде, то можно сделать `bytes([0b00000001])` или `0b00000001.to_bytes(1, 'big')`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за помощь, про биты и байты я знаю, что это двоичная система. Я правильно понимаю что после этих преобразований можно просту плюсануть к байтовой строке с информацией этот номер?